# recurrence relation for the number of ways to make a pile of $n$ poker chips using red, white, and blue chips

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

> Find a recurrence relation for the number of ways to make a pile of $n$ poker chips using red, white, and blue chips and such that no two red chips are together (consecutive).

My workings:

Consider the color of the top chip, if it is red, then he one below cannot be red and the remaining $n-2$ chips give $a_{n-2}$ different ways.

If it is not red, then the remaining $n-1$ chips give $a_{n-1}$ different ways. Then I believe my recurrence relation is

$$a_n = 2a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}$$

**My questions are the following:**
**1) are my workings correct?**
**2) should this be for n>2**
**3) is $a_1=3, a_2=8$ and why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) and 2) seem correct.

> is $a_1=3, a_2=8$ and why?

- If you have two poker chips you have 8 ways to make a pile without
  two consecutive red chips: $wb,bw,rw,wr,rb,br,ww, bb$. Or you
  calculate all possible ways and substract the $rr$ combination: $a_2=3^2-1=8$
- Similar for $a_1$: The are 3 ways without two consecutive red chips:
  $r,b,w\Rightarrow a_1=3$

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer!

Comment: @user104 You´re welcome.

Comment: is there a $a_0$ term?

Comment: @user104 No.You cannot make a pile of $0$ poker chips.

Comment: good point haha was hoping since now I am trying to solve this recurrence relation